# Connection refused en XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Tengo configurados los puertos de Apache y MySQL (4433 y 8080). Siempre me ha funcionado con 8080, pero hoy al poner en la dirección `http://localhost:8080/`, me da el siguiente mensaje:

> Connection refused: localhost:8080

He probado con 4433 pero tampoco funciona, ¿cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Por cierto, he notado que se ha reinstalado XAMPP, y he tenido que poner el idioma en inglés otra vez, no sé si es un problema de que al reinstalarlo (lo ha hecho solo), se hayan borrado las configuraciones.

Comment: Podría ser una serie de problemas de Windows. Difícil de decir sin mirar su configuración. Intente descargar y usar WAMP en su lugar. Utilizo WAMP en una de mis computadoras porque tenía problemas con XAMPP.

Comment: Hola, he instalado wamp y poniendo cualquier puerto me pone el mismo error. Me he fijado que si escribo el url con un puerto que no tengo configurado también me sale lo mismo

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, usaba opera con el turbo, y eso hacía que no se pudiera conectar, quité el turbo y me ha funcionado